# How to backtrack a pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, backtracking

Let say I have 2 pointers pointing to the same memory location. If I know what the address it is, how can I find out what pointers are pointing to that location?

```
int x=5;
int* p1=&x;
int* p2=&x;
```

How do I get the address of p1 and p2? Is it possible to even do this in C/C++? If not then is it possible to search through all pointers and see which ones have the value of &x?

Comment: Not possible, with a plain-old pointer. Need something smarter.

Comment: At runtime or in the debugger?

Comment: If you know where your pointers are you can sift through them to find the one that's pointing to the location of x. But it's tenuous.

Comment: No, but why do you need it; what are you trying to do?

Comment: … anyway, this is of course possible as it's the principle of a garbage collector. But the details are platform-specific. If at runtime, you need the operating system to tell you what memory regions are valid. We need to know the context you're working in.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, its not possible to "backtrack" a pointer in C or C++ (a good rule of thumb is if a feature has big hidden performance costs, then its not present in C or C++)

As for the second approach (going through memory looking for pointers), that is precisely what some tools like the [Boehm garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boehm_garbage_collector) do. However, not only is this process inneficient and not portable but it also can lead to "false positives" since you can't tell if a byte pattern in memory is a real pointer or something else like a regular integer or part of a string.

---

Anyway, you should ask yourself what is the real problem you need to solve instead of trying to hack a garbage collector on your own. Depending on  what you want to do there are many ways to approach it in C++ (RAII, smart pointers, etc)

Comment: "if a feature has big hidden performance costs, then its not present in C or C++" - tell that to <iostream>!